# Export framerate and resolution of video files into excel or txt file

Tags: windows, powershell

Hi I am trying to export the file information for a folder that holds videos to obtain the framerate and resolution of the files. I get alot of infomation using the code below but not what I am after.

```
Get-childitem | Export-Csv F:\list.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I think what you need is the command line version of [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), or see what you can do with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (something like `ffmpeg -i filename`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

The code you have now will export all properties of the FileInfo and/or DirectoryInfo objects returned by `Get-ChildItem`. None of which will have properties like video framerate of resolution.

To get info like that, you need to use the commandline version of [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), or see what you can do with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (something like ffmpeg -i filename)